# Communicating with a Marlin board via Javascript and Node SerialPort

Tags: marlin, g-code, serial-connection

I am trying to send G-codes to my Anycubic Kobra 3D printer running on a Marlin board.

I have tried several serial communication software (terminal-based) and managed to send `G28`, for example, and it works. Using the exact same baud rate and port name, I am using Node SerialPort library and I am successfully connecting to the board. But the problem is that it won't accept my commands, nothing happens.

I have been trying to send `G28` in ASCII and hex forms. I have also been trying with `G28\n` and `G28\n\r`.  I monitored the SerialPort with a tool while sending commands via both Cura and serial terminal. I then sent the exact same string with Node SerialPort, but it didn't work.

What is the correct format, any clues? I want to be able to send commands via Node SerialPort since I am doing my own web interface for the 3D Printer.